# Could not run a simple polymer app

Tags: html, polymer

OK..  I have configured [Polymer Project](https://www.polymer-project.org/) as it is in [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVR2gPS4rpU)

Project structure is :

[image]

My custom element is :

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="hello-world" noscript>
<template>
    <h1>Hi From Custom Element</h1>
</template>
</polymer-element>
```

index.html is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/polymer/polymer.js">
</script>
<link rel="import" href="elements/hello-world.html">
</head>
<body>
<hello-world></hello-world>
</body>
</html>
```

OK.. When I run this code without Server I get error :

```
 Imported resource from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

and when I run the app on WAMP I get error :

```
Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type 'HTML' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document'. 
 Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

in *polymer.js* any help in this case?

Comment: `Polymer.js` is the Polymer library that makes use of web components which is not required in order for the app to work. Load the `webcomponents.js` which is the Polyfill for web components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the nature of polymer you can't just run things with the `file:` URI. See https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/reusableelements.html

In the second case try loading your script from `bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js` instead of `bower_components/polymer/polymer.js`.